# Submitting a new version for review

Tags: discussion, iterative-review

I previously posted a class for review (~2 weeks ago).  It received some feedback.  I accepted a response.  I made changes per the review, then additional changes that were not motivated by the review.  I'd like to post the new version for additional review.  I'd like it to be open to anyone (not just the original reviewer).

Is this against any rules, or should I do this differently (than a new post), or is there anything else I should be doing additionally (e.g., include a link to the original)?

Comment: That sounds like a very routine follow-up question.

Comment: What differentiates this question from the other question?  I.e. what do you still want to know after reading the answer to the other question?